# Refactor conditional to polymorphism in spring-boot code

Tags: spring, polymorphism, refactoring, conditional-statements, code-cleanup

I have seen example given in Refactoring by Martin Fowler [Here](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html)

Not sure how I can implement it in spring-boot way(IoC).

I am working on spring web application.
I have a REST controller which accepts `studentId` and `fileType` and export data of *Students* in given `fileType` format.
Controller calls `ExportService` `exportFile()` method which looks like

```
@Service
public class ExportServiceImpl implements ExportService {
    public void exportFile(Integer studentId, String fileType) {
        if (XML.equals(fileType)) { exportXML(studentId);}
        else if()... // and so on for CSV, JSON etc
    }
}
```

To refactor conditional to polymorphism,

First I created abstract class,

```
abstract class ExportFile {
    abstract public void doExport(Integer studentId);
}
```

Then I create services for each fileType export. For example XML export following is a service,

```
@Service
public class ExportXMLFileService extends ExportFile {
    public void doExport(Integer studentId) {
        // exportLogic will create xml
    }
}
```

Now my ExportService should look like,

```
@Service
public class ExportServiceImpl implements ExportService {
    @Autowired
    private ExportFile exportFile;

    public void exportFile(Integer studentId, String fileType) {
        exportFile.doExport(studentId);
    }
}
```

Now here I am stuck :(

Could not get, 
How the `@Autowired` `ExportFile` will know which concrete service to refer based on `fileType`?

Please do correct me if I am wrong. Your response will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to implement Factory pattern. I did something similar like this. You'll have a `ExportServiceFactory` which will based on the specific input parameters return the concrete implementation of `ExportService`, something like this:

```
@Component
class ExportServiceFactory {

    @Autowired @Qualifier("exportXmlService")
    private ExportService exportXmlService;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("exportCsvService")
    private ExportService exportCsvService;

    public ExportService getByType(String fileType) {
         // Implement method logic here, for example with switch that will return the correct ExportService
    }

}
```

As you can see I have used Springs [`@Qualifier`](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/) which will be determining what implementation will be injected.

Then in your code whenever you will need to use `ExportService` you will inject the factory and fetch the correct implementation, e.g.

```
  ...
  @Autowired
  private ExportServiceFactory exportServiceFactory;

  ...
  // in method, do something like this
  exportServiceFactory.getByType(fileType).doExport();
```

I hope this will help you to get on the right track. As for the switch in the method of factory - it is OK, since you have now decouple the logic to retrieve specific implementation from the code that does not have anything to do with it.